# WCF Security Mode TransportWithMessageCredential

Tags: c#, wcf, authorization, transport

I've not a WCF service running as a windows service that I've converted to use the Custom UserNamePasswordValidator.

This all worked perfectly on the original setting of SecurityMode = "Transport".

However the only problem is that none of the faultexceptions would come back correctly.
I guessed this was because it needs to be a security mode of TransportWithMessageCredential.

The problem I have is when I set the security mode to be TransportWithMessageCredential the UserNamePasswordValidator validate method is now not hit.

Below is my app.config. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
      <!-- hidden -->
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="ThisApp.Global.Service.ServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour">
              <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="https://testapi.ThisApp.com" />
                </baseAddresses>
              </host>
              <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="ThisApp.Global.Service.IServiceImpl" />
            </service>
        </services>

      <!--WCF Service Binding Configurations-->
      <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="TransportSecurity">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>

      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
         <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
               <authorizationPolicies>
                 <add policyType="ThisApp.Global.Service.Security.AuthorizationPolicy, ThisApp.Global.Service" />
              </authorizationPolicies>
            </serviceAuthorization>
            <serviceCredentials>
              <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ThisApp.Global.Service.Security.CustomUserNameValidator, ThisApp.Global.Service" />
            </serviceCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
          initializeData="ThisApp Global API" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include transport in the binding security section, thus:

```
<binding name="TransportSecurity">
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this makes no difference. Any attempt to access the service results in : The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action  is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings.

Comment: Also made a quick edit above as this is running as a windows service and therefore is an app.config rather than web. Cheers

Comment: huh. I'm doing similar. basicHttpBinding with an IIS hosted service using custom auth manager. All I needed was the above config.

Comment: Cheers. Can only assume it's something to do with me running it as a service instead.